# I know how to do it with K Maps but how to solve it without using them

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary, karnaugh-map

Let X=X1X0 and Y=Y1Y0 be unsigned 2-bit numbers. The output function F = 1 if X is
equal to or less than Y and F = 0 otherwise. Find the minimized expression for F?

Comment: the method is the same,  the Karnaugh map is just a trick to make the problem easier on our monkey brains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks like homework, so I'll nudge you in the right direction.

Write down all the cases for which \$F = 1\$ as products of \$X_1\$, \$X_0\$, \$Y_1\$ and \$Y_0\$ and add them together. For example, if \$X_1=X_0=Y_1=Y_0=0\$, then \$F=1\$, hence \$\overline{X}_1\overline{X}_0\overline{Y}_1\overline{Y}_0\$ is one of your terms.

Alternatively, you can add all the cases for which \$F=0\$, negate the whole expression and use De Morgan's law to rewrite it as a product of sums, but this only makes sense if you have considerably less cases where \$F=0\$.

After you find your direct expression, simplify it.